# click event fired more than once ( supposed to be once)

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

this is my first post, here I wanted to create a chrome extension, when it is pressed, it will show links which can be pressed, links retrieved using AJAX. It worked so far, the only problem is when it is clicked on any link, sometimes it appeared twice or even thrice. can anyone give an explanation and answer to this problem?

Thank you!

```
var links = [];
links.push("http://www.tenmanga.com/book/rss/id-16896.xml");
links.push("http://mangafox.me/rss/fairy_tail.xml");
links.push("http://feeds.feedburner.com/9gag?format=xml");
```

Function Start()

```
function start(){
    for (var i in links)
        getXML(links[i]);
    $(document).ready(function(){
    });


}
```

Function getXML

```
function getXML(url){
    var test = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml){
            parse(xml);
bind();
        }
    });
    return test;
}

function bind(){
    $("a").click(function(e){
        chrome.tabs.create({url:$(this).attr("href")});
    });
}
function parse(xml){
    //$("#content").append();
    var title = $(xml).find('title').first().text();
    var createClickHandler = function(arg){
        return function(){ 
            open_item(arg); 
        };
    }
    $("#content").append(title+"<br>");
    $(xml).find('item').each(function(){
        var temp = document.createElement("a");
        var title = this.childNodes[1].textContent;
        var link = this.childNodes[3].textContent;
        temp.innerHTML = title;
        temp.setAttribute("href",link);
        $("#content").append(temp);
        $("#content").append("<br>");
    });
    $("#content").append("<br>");
}
```

START HERE!

```
var start = start();
```

Comment: I used bind() function which is $('a').click, and I put bind() inside ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of binding on each link, do the following once:

```
$(document).on('click','a'
    function(e){
        chrome.tabs.create({url:$(this).attr("href")});
        return false;
    }
);
```

if you have no other anchors on link

Comment: @willsantoso: and put this `on` call in the main `document.ready` handler, not inside some callback, because that will create multiple event listeners. This code uses event delegation, so you'll only ever need 1 handler

Answer (score 1):

The only reason to invoke click event more than once when clicked on an elements is, more than one event handler is registered over that. Each time you call bind what u have done is binding to event to 'a' so i guess for the first link it event is fired once for the seconds twice and for the third thrice.May be instead of using just $('a') that attributes to all the 'a' element in the page you may dynamically make 'a' with separate ids. That must end the weird behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Invoke `e.preventDefault();` where `e` is `event` in your click callback so that event won't bubble up and won't trigger anything else.

Also bind() should not be called on each success after ajax returned.

Comment: i not sure that `e.preventDefault()` really need that, but yes, answer is that on each link you bind to 'a' link

Comment: I guess he does need that because he manually creates tabs with the link so I guess he doesn't want to follow the link on same tab he clicked it.

Comment: I used `e.preventDefault()`and it seemed not working, btw, where should I put 'bind()'? sorry it's kinda messy codes.. :)